tabularray : use of "@{ ... }" in tblr
I'm trying to setup a tblr environment to make it look like a bullet list. So i need to make the table generate a bullet at the start of every new line. Here's my try, it seems to work but i get the following warning:
Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 9--10
[][] 

mwe:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{rowsep=6pt,column{2}={font=\bfseries},colspec={@{$\bullet$}p{6pt}@{}@{}p{.15\linewidth}X}}
  & pomme & la pomme est un fruit acide bon pour la santé \\
  & poire & la poire est un fruit bon pour la cuisine  \\
  & cerise & la cerise est parfaite pour les tartes \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}

It seems that tblr does not properly handle @{...} expression.
Using @{...} is only  to avoid having to write $\bullet$ at
every line.
Keep in mind that it must look like a bullet list.

tabularray has its own column specification style

It's actually perfectly alright to use @{} and >{\textbullet}l in the colspec part of a tblr environment.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex} \ifpdftex\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\fi
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tblr}{rowsep=6pt, column{1}={font=\bfseries},
   colspec={@{} >{\textbullet\ }l X[l] }}
   pomme  & la pomme est un fruit acide bon pour la santé \\
   poire  & la poire est un fruit bon pour la cuisine \\
   cerise & la cerise est parfaite pour les tartes 
\end{tblr}

\end{document}


it seems putting \noindent  is important, otherwise i get that Overfull ... warning

@user1850133 - Indeed, the default width of the two-column tblr environment (with at least 1 X-type column) is \textwidth. Without the \noindent directive, this environment's left-hand edge would come in at \parindent and its right-hand edge would come in at \textwidth+\parindent -- causing LaTeX to issue an "Overfull hbox" warning. That's why I provided the \noindent instruction.

You can use preto to add bullets before every column.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{rowsep=6pt,column{1}={font=\bfseries,preto={$\bullet$\ }}}
  pomme & la pomme est un fruit acide bon pour la santé \\
  poire & la poire est un fruit bon pour la cuisine  \\
  cerise & la cerise est parfaite pour les tartes \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}



Here with a colspec={X[.2,l]X} i get that Overfull ... warning. But if \noindent is present in the preamble, it seems fine.
